# java.io.FileNotFoundException ошибка в Apache poi, android

Tags: java, android, apache-poi

Нужно открыть xlsx файл в Android, использую apache poi, но получаю ошибку "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file/sdcard/Download/file.xlsx (No such file or directory)"

Делаю так:
1. Через интент открываю пикер

```
Intent xlsxPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        xlsxPickerIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        xlsxPickerIntent.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(xlsxPickerIntent, REQUEST_CODE.OPENEXTERNAL);
```

2. В onActivityResult получаю Uri и вызываю метод

   ```
         Uri xlsxFileUri = data.getData();
          importXlsx(xlsxFileUri);
   ```
3. Сам метод

   ```
   public void importXlsx(Uri uri) {
   try {
           FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(uri.getEncodedPath()));
           XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   }
   ```

В манифесте разрешение на запись/чтение есть, проверка на PERMISSION_GRANTED тоже. Apache poi версия 3.17

Comment: На какой версии ОС запускаете? Если на 9-10, то там сильно ограничили работу с диском. Попробуйте на более старой версии ОС запустить.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Само устройство у меня android 8.1, в build.gradle compileSdkVersion 29, targertSdk Version 29, minSdkVerison 22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В новых версиях Android механизм работы с файловой системой сильно ограничен. Теперь паттерн действий (для вашего случая, когда требуется "открыть" файл) должен быть такой:

1) Через `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` вызывается системный пикер файла (вы это и делаете)

2) Получив ссылку на файл, нужно открыть поток чтения из `Uri` через `ContentResolver` в виде `openInputStream()` - этого у вас нет

3) Далее создать файл в частном хранилище `new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);`

4) Записать ваш поток (из шага 2) в этот созданный файл

5) И теперь открыть этот файл (созданный в шаге 3 и скопированный в шаге 4) своим POI

Смысл в том, что внешние файлы вам доступны только как `InputStream` (то есть для чтения), а если нужно открыть файл как нормальный файл, то он должен находиться в частном каталоге приложения в `context.getFilesDir()`

Comment: Можно подробнее ваш второй пункт в виде кода? Файл в частном каталоге создал, но не знаю как открыть и записать поток через ContentResolver

Comment: `InputSream is=context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)` - примерно так (за точность не ручаюсь)

Comment: спасибо, а как теперь это записать именно в тот созданный файл?

Comment: Открываешь на созданный файл `FileOutputStream`, читаешь из `InputStream` и пишешь их в `FileOutputStream` - не забудь в конце закрыть поток.

Comment: да это я понимаю, какой конкретно метод нужен, что бы FileOutputStream принял на вход InputStream? Не по битам через цикл же это делать.

Comment: Пример [здесь](https://www.baeldung.com/java-copy-file)

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло создать копию файла, но при создании книги в apache poi из полученного файла возникает ошибка, такая же, которая возникала когда я хотел создать книгу сразу из потока ( минуя создание копии файла в директории приложения). Буду разбираться в проблемах apache poi на android